# Monitor MySQL Connection and Request

Tags: mysql, tcpdump

I'm trying to monitor all incoming connections to a mysql database. I've used

```
tcpdump port 3306 and '(tcp-syn|tcp-ack)!=0'
```

currently which is showing connections but is there a way to also see what it is sending/receiving?

Currently I see:

```
11:45:43.275498 IP ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql > ip-10-0-21-17.ec2.internal.35522: Flags [.], ack 1780, win 248, options [nop,nop,TS val 2559781727 ecr 625071366], length 0
11:45:43.277761 IP ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql > ip-10-0-21-17.ec2.internal.35522: Flags [P.], seq 519:538, ack 1780, win 248, options [nop,nop,TS val 2559781729 ecr 625071366], length 19
11:45:43.277799 IP ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql > ip-10-0-41-109.ec2.internal.60718: Flags [P.], seq 32662:32900, ack 1, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 2559781729 ecr 2559505629], length 238
11:45:43.278331 IP ip-10-0-41-109.ec2.internal.60718 > ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql: Flags [.], ack 32900, win 24565, options [nop,nop,TS val 2559505675 ecr 2559781729], length 0
11:45:43.278345 IP ip-10-0-21-17.ec2.internal.35522 > ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 1780:1989, ack 538, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 625071368 ecr 2559781729], length 209
11:45:43.280364 IP ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql > ip-10-0-21-17.ec2.internal.35522: Flags [P.], seq 538:596, ack 1989, win 258, options [nop,nop,TS val 2559781732 ecr 625071368], length 58
11:45:43.280375 IP ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql > ip-10-0-41-109.ec2.internal.60718: Flags [P.], seq 32900:33171, ack 1, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 2559781732 ecr 2559505675], length 271
11:45:43.280971 IP ip-10-0-21-17.ec2.internal.35522 > ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 1989:1994, ack 596, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 625071371 ecr 2559781732], length 5
11:45:43.280983 IP ip-10-0-21-17.ec2.internal.35522 > ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql: Flags [F.], seq 1994, ack 596, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 625071371 ecr 2559781732], length 0
11:45:43.281003 IP ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql > ip-10-0-21-17.ec2.internal.35522: Flags [F.], seq 596, ack 1995, win 258, options [nop,nop,TS val 2559781733 ecr 625071371], length 0
11:45:43.281011 IP ip-10-0-41-109.ec2.internal.60718 > ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql: Flags [.], ack 33171, win 24565, options [nop,nop,TS val 2559505677 ecr 2559781732], length 0
11:45:43.281553 IP ip-10-0-21-17.ec2.internal.35522 > ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql: Flags [.], ack 597, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 625071372 ecr 2559781733], length 0
```

I was hoping for something like:

```
11:45:43.281011 IP ip-10-0-41-109.ec2.internal.60718 > ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql: Flags [.], ack 33171, win 24565, options [nop,nop,TS val 2559505677 ecr 2559781732], length 0 'select userid from users where email = 'example@example.com''
11:45:43.277799 IP ip-10-0-40-123.ec2.internal.mysql > ip-10-0-41-109.ec2.internal.60718: Flags [P.], seq 32662:32900, ack 1, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 2559781729 ecr 2559505629], length 238 '1234'
```

where the last values are what the DB is processing/returning

Comment: MySQL Workbench allows you to view all connections and their queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood it right, what you want is to see the payload that is sent in the communication.

I don't know if the communication between the client and the mySQL server is encrypted, but if its not you can add more parameters to the tcdump command.

try something of this sort

```
tcpdump -vv port 3306 and '(tcp-syn|tcp-ack)!=0' -nnttttA
```

This should show the payload in ASCII

Comment: This looks close. The return is `2020-01-22 09:56:04.437977 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 44011, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 705)
    10.0.21.17.37018 > 10.0.40.123.3306: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0fa7 (correct), seq 385:1038, ack 213, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 704892527 ecr 2639602889], length 653
E.....@.@.:.
...
.({......g7...n...........
*..o.U$......INSERT into table
   (columns)
   VALUES (values)` Do you know what the `E.....@.@.:.
...
.({......g7...n...........
*..o.U$......` is?

Comment: might be the package information.